# Using PHP mySQL with CSV data containing BOM

Tags: php, mysql, csv, byte-order-mark, fgetcsv

I have a database that holds stock levels for certain items that are supplied by different suppliers. Each supplier sends me a daily CSV file with their current stock levels. I am trying to update the stock levels into my database.

The problem I am having is that when I extract the data from the CSV and send it through queries, it is not being working properly.

I have echoed the queries prior to sending them and the output is fine. Using phpMyAdmin, if I just paste the code as it is echoed, it works fine. This has led me to believe that it is an encoding problem.

Viewing the CSV file in cPanel File Manager I see there is an odd character at the beginning of the file. (I believe this is caleld a BOM). If I delete this characted and save the CSV file then my code works perfectly and the databse updates as expected.

[image]

Editing the file in cPanel File Manager, the Encoding opens as ansi_x3.110-1983. While manually deleting the character will fix the issue, it is not an option as I want this to be a fully automated daily process.

My code to open the file and extract the data from CSV:

```
// Open File        
$csvData = fopen($file, "r");
       
if($csvData !== FALSE)
{
  while(!feof($csvData))
  {
      $csvRow[] = fgetcsv($csvData, 100);
  }
}

// Close file
fclose($csvData);
```

My code to build a simple search query

```
foreach($csvRow as $row)
{
  $searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM supplier WHERE supplierItemCode = '".$row[0]."'";
  $result = $conn->query($searchQuery);
  echo "<br>".$searchQuery;
  if($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
      // CODE NEVER REACHES HERE
  }
```

As mentioned, if I simply paste the echo of `$searchQuery` into phpMyAdmin and run the query it works fine.

I have tried using `fseek($csvData, 2)` which successfully removes the BOM characters from the first row of data, but that is having no effect.

As suggested, I have tried using

```
$csvData = fopen($file, "r");
$BOM = null;
if($csvData !== FALSE)
{
   $BOM = fread($csvData, 3);
   if($BOM !==  FALSE)
   {
      if($BOM != "\xef\xbb\xbf")
      {
         echo "<h5>BOM: ".$BOM; // This code is executed every time
         fseek($csvData, 0);
      }
   }
   //fseek($csvData, 2); // This was my earlier attempts without the above BOM filter
   while(!feof($csvData))
   {
      $csvRow[] = fgetcsv($csvData, 100);
   }
}
```

Using the BOM filter method produces this output.
[image: Sample output]

As a further note, you'll notice that in my Update query output, there is a blank space in the SET quantity column. This space is not visible in the csv file.

This query is built with

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE supplier SET ".$supplier." = '".$row[2]."' WHERE supplierItemCode = '".$row[0]."'";
```

Any suggestions on what exactly is causing this issue and how I can get around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by, "I have tried using fseek($csvData, 2) which successfully removes the BOM characters from the first row of data, but that is having no effect." That seems contradictory to me,

Comment: Hi Booboo. I mean I used `fseek($csvData, 2);` before the `while` loop and extracting the data from the CSV.
This removed the BOM characters from the first element in first line of the CSV file, but it had no effect on the SQL. None of my queries work unless I delete the BOM characters from the CSV file and then re save it. The my code works fine.

Comment: I mean if it *successfully* removes the BOM, why would it have no effect?

Comment: I don't understand either. Hence why I've come here for help. I'd never heard of BOM data before researching this problem. Perhaps it doesn't work the way I think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution to work. After doing a lot of investigating, I believed it was encoded in UTF-16, despite what the BOM characters may have been saying.

I just wrote a simple function to convert each CSV value I was passing to the SQL.

```
function Convert($str)
    {
        return mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE");
    }

........

$updateQuery = "UPDATE supplier SET ".$supplier." = '".Convert($row[2])."' WHERE supplierItemCode = '".Convert($row[0])."'";
```

I'm not sure why the BOM was causing such issue and why removing it entirely was not working. Thanks for everyone's help that lead me to discover the encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification to the code that opens and reads the CSV file. It checks for the presence of the BOM and bypasses it if present:

```
$cvsRow = [];
// Open File
$csvData = fopen($file, "r");
if($csvData !== FALSE)
{
  $BOM = fread($csvData, 4); // read potential BOM sequences to see if one is present or not
  if ($BOM !== FALSE)
  {
    if (strlen($BOM) >= 3 && substr_compare($BOM, "\xef\xbb\xbf", 0, 3) == 0)
    {
      fseek($csvData, 3); // found UTF-8 encoded BOM
    }
    elseif (strlen($BOM) >= 2 && (substr_compare($BOM, "\xfe\xff", 0, 2) == 0 || substr_compare($BOM, "\xff\xfe", 0, 2) == 0))
    {
      fseek($csvData, 2); // found UTF-16 encoded BOM
    }
    elseif ($BOM != "\00\00\xfe\xff" && $BOM != "\xff\xfe\00\00")
    {
      fseek($csvData, 0); // did not find UTF-32 encoded BOM
    }
    while(!feof($csvData))
    {
        $csvRow[] = fgetcsv($csvData, 100);
    }
  }
  // Close file (only if it has been successfully opened)
  fclose($csvData);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. Although I'm not quite sure why. Isn't it just checking if the first 3 characters are the BOM, and if so, skipping them? I already know the BOM is there so isn't `fseek($csvData, 2)` doing the exact same thing?

Comment: This code conditionally skips over the BOM if and only if it is present, so it is a general solution that should work with any CSV file. As to why your `fseek` did not work (I would think it should as long as the BOM *is* present), you did not actually post any code with the `fseek` so I cannot say. If you wish, update your question with the `fseek` you said you used but did not work. And send me a comment here when you have done this and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I just noticed: you need to do fseek($csvData, 3); to skip the first 3 bytes.

Comment: Apologies Booboo. I just realised that this solution is not working. The file I first tried it on was one that I had modified. I have just tried again on the 3 files that are untouched, directly as I recieve them and it is not working. It is not detecting the characters as BOM. I will update my question with screenshots.

Comment: It sounds like the character(s) in question are either not a true BOM, or are a BOM in a different format. Apparently BOMs can be 2, 3, or 4 bytes long, and can be in one of five formats: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark. Try this script to dump the ordinal value of the first 5 chars: `$file = 'yourfile.csv';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
for ( $i=0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
echo "$i: " . ord($i) . "\n";
}` Then show us the results here.

Comment: Hi kmoser. The output of your suggestion was 0: 48 1: 49 2: 50 3: 51 4: 52

Comment: I'm tried this code to get the ord value of the `$BOM` I was capturing before. `for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { $byte = substr($BOM, $i); echo "$i: ".ord($byte)."\n"; }` This produced 0: 255 1: 254 2: 0 3: 0 4: 0

Comment: I've updated the code to detect any of the possible BOM sequences. Give it a try.

Comment: *This produced 0: 255 1: 254 2: 0 3: 0 4: 0*. But I don't understand why a byte at offset 4 would be 0. The updated code only handles 2, 3 and 4-byte BOM codes.

Comment: Hi Booboo. I have updated my code with the sample you supplied. It is correctly stripping the BOM characters from the first row of CSV data. By that I mean that the first element displays correctly when echoed as 'Item Code'. However the problem still remains. For some reason the 3rd column, Qty, echoes out with a blank space behind it. It's like the new line charcter at the end of each line is being printed as a white space character. I cannot explain why this is happening.

Comment: I've just used `ord()` to echo the contents of the first column of data. There is a null byte between each character. This leads me to believe the data is encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: @AshleyShirley Interestingly, [UTF-32 (LE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) represents a BOM as `FF FE 00 00` (the same code sequence in your file) which leads me to believe the file was encoded as UTF-32LE. I wonder if your solution would have worked just as well with `mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "UTF-32LE")`.

Comment: Hi kmoser, out of interest I did try converting to UTF-32LE but it did not work. All the characters just displayed as ?? when I did an echo of the query.

Comment: *After* you bypass any of the 3 possible BOMs that might be present using the code I suggest, read in the rest of the file as string `$text`, for example, and then `echo mb_detect_encoding($text);` to see what the *actual* encoding PHP thinks it is.